# VMWare Hypervisor vSphere 5 - VM static ip from VLAN NAT

Tags: vmware-esxi, nat, static-ip

I have a VMWare vSphere 5 Hypervisor server that has a static ip address assigned to it by VLAN that is configured to perform NAT. The static IP is assigned to the bare metal server via the NIC's mac address.

I want to setup a guest machine to also have a static ip address, how can I go about having this setup? I have assigned a IP for the guest's MAC Address but it doesn't seem to be working as when I ping the ip address it does not respond. The guest is running ubuntu 10.04 server edition. I am trying to assign it a static public ip address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean 'assigned to it by VLAN'? Do you mean by a DHCP server based on MAC? We'll need you to be a bit clearer on this please as the question doesn't make 100% sense right now. By the way if you want to set a static IP in a guest then that's how you do it, in the guest - anything else isn't a static.

Comment: Yes, assigned by the DHCP server based on the MAC address. To refine the question, I want to assigned a static external ip address (public) to a guest os, not an internal static ip address.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info. Firstly most sysadmins on SF hate using DHCP for servers, it's a single, very fragile and easily hacked, point of failure. It's also wrong to use the term static when using DHCP, it's really a 'DHCP Reservation'. That said these are fine for VMs and simply need either a Layer 2 path from DHCP server to client and if they're on a different segment then you'll also need a 'DHCP Helper' line in your router config to tell the router what to do with clients on one segment asking for DHCP addresses. It's as simple as that. Describe your networking better and we can help.

Answer (score 1):

A VMWare ESX server should not have networking configured on any physical NIC; it is not meant to work this way.

To reach the hypervisor, you connect the kernel network to a virtual switch or port group, which is then assigned to one or more physical NICs.

This kernel network can then have the hypervisor IP assigned.

If your server only has a single physical NIC, you'll have to add the service console to the only existing virtual switch and port group.